# vb.net counting label texts

Tags: vb.net, count, label

well i'm pretty stuck at counting how many labels say ( enabled ) that i got.

I got 10 labels that their default text says "Enabled" but also buttons to change their text to "Disabled"

So i want to count how many Enabled buttons i got out of 10.

7/10 or 5/10 or 1/10 etc...

Tried :

```
Dim Number1 As Double
Dim Number2 As Double
Dim Number3 As Double
Dim result As Double

 If Label100.Text = "Enabled" Then
            num1.Text = "1"
        ElseIf Label100.Text = "Disabled" Then
            num1.Text = "0"
        End If
        Number1 = num1.Text
        Number2 = num2.Text
        Number3 = num3.Text
        result = Number1 + Number2 + Number3
        StatsCount.Text = result
```

I made labels next to the Enabled/Disabled labels that give you number of 1 if Enabled and 0 if Disabled but doesn't work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to count labels. OK

```
Private Sub HowManyEnabled()
        Dim Count As Integer = 0
        For Each ctr As Control In Controls
            If TypeOf ctr Is Label Then
                If CType(ctr, Label).Text = "Enabled" Then
                    Count += 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print($"There are {Count} enabled labels")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of the labels unless you are creating an app for visually impaired. Buttons are "greyed out" when disabled so you already have a visual clue. To count loop through the controls looking for buttons and check their enabled property.

```
Private Sub HowManyEnabled()
        Dim Count As Integer = 0
        For Each ctr As Control In Controls
            If TypeOf ctr Is Button Then
                If CType(ctr, Button).Enabled Then
                    Count += 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print($"There are {Count} enabled buttons")
End Sub
```

If you are not using the latest vb then

```
Debug.Print(String.Format("There are {0} enabled buttons", Count))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and here is a picture on how it looks like : http://prntscr.com/ivoxxf  there is buttons to change the labels text to disabled so i want it to count the enabled only

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! +repp <3 you saved me really!